# How can I restrict minimum and maximum hours in a datetime field in Dynamics 365 on-premise?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-365

I need to limit the visible hours in datepicker. I tried the code below but it did not work:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("contentIFrame0");
var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("new_starttime_iTime.00:00")[0];
elmnt.style.display = "none";
```

Is there an attribute like minHour, maxHour that I can reach using:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("new_starttime").minHour = 9
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done using the regular datepicker control. Also, fiddling with the HTML is not supported and/or recommended.

Instead you could consider developing a custom PCF control. Building it from scratch is not necessary. There are plenty open source examples available. Check out the [PCF Gallery](https://pcf.gallery/categories#date) for example.